# How do i subtract from multiplier row , from 2 table? mySQL

Tags: mysql, subtraction

I have been trying for hours search around for a way to subtract from multiplier row , from 2 table? As I keep getting error from mySQL workbench.

I have 2 table `hotel`, `hotel_stay`

I need to get the number of unique room then minus the individual capacity

```
+--------------------+------------------+
hotel_stay
+--------------------+------------------+
room (PK)
99
99
10
10
10

+--------------------+------------------+
hotel  
+--------------------+------------------+ 
room(FK)  |   capacity
99        |   10
10        |   12
```

Output will be on the same table as the hotel or I will have to us AS?

```
room | capacity
99   | 8      
10   | 9
```

Comment: Can you take another run at describing you data? I tried to edit it to make it readable, but I am not really sure how your tables are intended to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your question. But you can us something like this to get the total capacity for each room:

```
select h.room, 
   (h.capacity - hs.TotalBooked) as Capacity
from hotel h
inner join 
(
    select COUNT(room) as TotalBooked, 
       Room
    from hotel_stay
    group by room
) hs
    on h.room = hs.room
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56159/2). This returns the result:

```
| ROOM | CAPACITY |
-------------------
|   10 |        9 |
|   99 |        8 |
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply, will try this
But 1 question
What does this code do hs.TotalRoom Capacity ?

- EDIT -
OMG! THANK! 
I was searching for 3 hours, thanks man. Will keep this code aside for future reference

Comment: @KelvinSeah the `hs.TotalRoom` is the count from the subquery. I just gave it that name, you can change the alias.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! Should have asked this question long ago instead of finding it for 3 hours to no avail. Will keep this for future refernce

Comment: @KelvinSeah Happy to help.  If you find this answer helpful, then consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.  It will help future visitors to the site and you will get site rep for accepting.

Comment: Did that and one last question what does inner join do, i saw this some explanation and couldn't understand?

Comment: @KelvinSeah the `INNER JOIN` connects the two tables using the `room` number.  If you need help learning joins here is a great visual explanation of them -- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html